# Linear Carousel with wrap enabled

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, icarousel

I want to make a carousel that's linear WITH wrap enabled (so you can scroll indefinitely in either direction and it'll just wrap around)  They have a CarouselType.Linear, but it isn't wrap enabled.  Anyone know of how to do this with either iCarousel or UICollectionViews?  I can't find any good resources on how to make a Custom iCarousel layout...  Any good references there?

[Alliance Carousel](https://components.xamarin.com/view/Alliance.Carousel)

```
        this.Carousel = new CarouselView(frame)
        {
            DataSource = new CylindericalDataSource(this),
            Delegate = new CylindericalDelegate(this)
        };
        this.Carousel.CarouselType = CarouselType.Linear;
        this.Carousel.ConfigureView();
        this.View.AddSubview(this.Carousel);
```

------------EDIT--------------

To answer @Rahul's question

```
    public override void DidScroll (CarouselView carouselView)
    {
        base.DidScroll (carouselView);

        nint numOfItems = carouselView.NumberOfItems;
        if (this._parentController != null &&
            this._parentController._studioViewController != null &&
            this._parentController._studioViewController.SuccessfullyReceivedProjectAndPageData () &&
            this._parentController._studioViewController.HasFlowCardCarouselFinishedLoading () &&
            numOfItems > 0)
        {
            // Enforce min and max values fro ScrollOffset so the user can't scroll the carousel off screen.  This is required when wrapping is turned off. 
            nfloat maxScrollOffset = ((nfloat)numOfItems) - 1f;
            nfloat minScrollOffset = 0f;
            if (carouselView.ScrollOffset < minScrollOffset)
            {
                carouselView.ScrollOffset = minScrollOffset;
            }
            if (carouselView.ScrollOffset > maxScrollOffset)
            {
                carouselView.ScrollOffset = maxScrollOffset;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  Override the **ValueForOption** method and force the **CarouseOption.Wrap** to be equal to 1.0f.  See below

```
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Class: CylindericalDelegate
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    public class CylindericalDelegate : CarouselViewDelegate
    {

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // Constructors
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public CylindericalDelegate()
        {
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        // CylindericalDelegate Implementation
        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

        public override nfloat ValueForOption(CarouselView carousel, CarouselOption option, nfloat aValue)
        {
            if (option == CarouselOption.Spacing)
            {
                return aValue * 1.1f;
            }
            if (option == CarouselOption.Wrap)
            {
                return 1.0f;
            }
            return aValue;
        }

        /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: thanks.. and what if I want to stop carousel on last image / slide?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not built in when using it like this.  I attached my code that was responsible from that behavior of stopping on the last image.  You have to override DidScroll and enforce it yourself by using ScrollOffset.  The scrollOffset is based on the indexes not the frame.